# Kotlin: Creating a mutable map from list of pairs, and not varargs?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list in Kotlin. I need to create a map from every element of the list, to an empty mutable set, something like this -

```
var mutableMap: MutableMap<Int, MutableSet<Int>> = mutableMapOf(someList.map{ it to mutableSetOf<Int>() })
```

But I'm getting this error -

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Pair<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>
Found:
List<Pair<Int, MutableSet<Int>>>
```

I know that mutableMapOf() accepts `varargs pairs`, so I tried the spread operator (`*`), but that also didnt work. Please help me achieve the result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spread operator is for Arrays, not Lists. Also, if you define your variable type as a Map of Sets instead of a MutableMap of MutableSets, you are casting it to be read-only. So to fix your code:

```
var mutableMap: MutableMap<Int, MutableSet<Int>> = mutableMapOf(*someList.map{ it to mutableSetOf<Int>() }.toTypedArray())
```

But it would be cleaner to do:

```
val map = someList.associateWith { mutableSetOf<Int>() }.toMutableMap()
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `mutableMapOf()` with arguments; there's a handy extension function on the list which can do it for you: [`toMap()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-map.html).

Unfortunately, there's no corresponding `toMutableMap()`.  One way would be to convert to a read-only map, and then convert *that* to a mutable map:

```
val mutableMap = someList.toMap().toMutableMap()
```

A slightly more complex but more efficient way would be to provide the resulting map:

```
val mutableMap = someList.toMap(mutableMapOf())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
val mutableMap: Map<Int, MutableSet<Int>> = someIntList.associateWith { mutableSetOf<Int>() }
```

Comment: Ya, this works. But i was wrong with the datatypes, sorry for that. I have edited them now. Also, this solution will solve this particular use case, though it wont help create a mutable map from list of pairs in general.